# CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable devices

Tags: iphone, core-motion, apple-m7

I want to use *CMMotionActivityManager*, I would like to know what devices motion data is available on? Many of the places that i have read suggest that it is currently only on devices that have the M7 chip.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMMotionActivityManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[isActivityAvailable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CMMotionActivityManager/isActivityAvailable) will return true on the M7 equipped devices:

```
iPhone5S
iPad mini with retina
iPad Air
```

Apple is not telling implicitly in the documentation, perhaps leaving other implementation options open and allowing the customer to disable the tracking sensor for privacy reasons.