# what are CMMotionActivityManager available device in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am just developing a sample Application to track user Activities with `CMMotionActivityManager` like Running and walking etc.

I tested it with my iPad Mini, and its not working. 
Code I written was below,

```
if ([CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable]) {
        self.activityManager = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];
        [self.activityManager startActivityUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                              withHandler:
         ^(CMMotionActivity *activity) {


         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if ([activity stationary]) {
                 NSLog(@"Stationary");
             }
             else if ([activity walking]) {
                 NSLog(@"Walking");
             }
             else if ([activity running]) {
                 NSLog(@"Running");
             }
             else if ([activity automotive]) {
                 NSLog(@"Vehicle");
             }
             else if ([activity cycling]) {
                 NSLog(@"Cycling");
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Unknown");
             }
         });
     }];
}`
```

So was only some devices supports Activity Manager.If so what are them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767508/cmmotionactivitymanager-isactivityavailable-devices
My guess is that the list shows (in its time) oldest possible device that supports it (M7 or equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I got the solution.

My iPAD mini does not have support for CMMotionActivityManager, I tested the same code with iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus, it worked pretty good.